# how to use jrebel + glassfish + static web files

Tags: glassfish, jrebel

As a first step of adopting jrebel, I would like each static file changed (html, js, css, etc.) to be synced with my glassfish application's folder. 
I use intellij. Can anyone suggest what exactly I need to do?

thanks,
Mattan.

Answer (score 1):

You need a rebel.xml configuration file to be present in the WEB-INF/classes of your web archive. It then points to the locations where the compiled classes and static resources should be discovered by JRebel.

See the documentation here: http://manuals.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/standalone/config.html

The <web> element in rebel.xml is the one responsible for mapping the resources.

If you're using IntelliJ IDEA, in JRebel tool window, web you enable JRebel for the particular module, the plugin generates rebel.xml automatically. If you're using maven, then there is JRebel Maven plugin that can generate rebel.xml files for all the submodules when building the archive.

Hope this helps.